# C# Regex Anomaly

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a bit perplexed here.

I have a Regex which is to limit decimal places to two points.
My second and third captures work as expected. But including the 1st capture `($1)` corrupts the string and includes all the decimal places (I get the original string).

```
var t = "553.17765";
var from = @"(\d+)(\.*)(\d{0,2})";
var to = "$1$2$3";
var rd = Regex.Replace(t, from,to);
var r = Regex.Match(t, from);
```

Why can't I get the 553 in the $1 variable?
[LinqPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqlR.png)

Comment: *"I have a Regex which is to limit decimal places to two points."* - can't you just parse it as double and.. string format it?

Comment: also, you could just `ToString()` the `r` variable. you should have your result.

Comment: Is this not the expected result? https://ideone.com/Nc6iUW

Comment: Looks like replace thinks two possible matches are better than one. First \d+ and \.*, Ignoring \d{0,2} because it is optional. Then matching \d+ and ignoring the rest because it is optional. I'd have to reread into how the matching algorithm works to tell you the exact reason though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are matching the number multiple times, once before the `.` and once after. You could work around that by looking for the longest match, but it seems you could [improve your Regex](https://regexr.com/6spvj) instead

```
(\d+\.?\d{0,2})
```

Steps are as follows

- The capture group covers the whole number at once.
- Look for digits, greedy match.
- Look for a decimal point, either one or none.
- Look for zero to two digits

Furthermore, if you want to *replace* using `Regex.Replace` you need something to match the rest of the string.

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, @".+?(\d+\.?\d{0,2}).+", "$1");
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FO5iEC)

Comment: This find/replace breaks with a shorter string so 553 returns 55.

Comment: Cannot repro https://dotnetfiddle.net/2NWtpZ

Comment: If the original string is only numbers the leading .+ removes the first number.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, also I wasn't aware that for the find/replace to work that you need something to match the rest of the string. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Refined your answer to (\d+\.?\d{0,2}).* and it works perfectly, thanks again!

Comment: Because what you are telling Regex is: find this match and replace it with `$1` capture. So if you only match the actual capture then the capture will just be replaced with itself. You need to match all the characters you want to replace. To be honest, if you are replacing the whole string it's probably easier to just use `Regex.Match` and pull out the capture

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not work because it triggers twice per definition. The statement `(\d+)(\.*)(\d{0,2})` will split the string `553.17765` as follows:

```
Match 1: 533.17
    $1 = 553
    $2 = .
    $3 = 17
    Replace 533.17 with 553.17
Match 2: 765
    $1 = 765
    Replace 765 with 765
```

The first match includes - as expected - only two of the decimal places. With this action, the match is complete and the regex starts looking for the next match, because Replace replaces *all* matches, not the first one only. As you can see, this regex does nothing by design.

The way replace works btw. is to find a match and replace the whole match with the replace pattern. So no need to include the surrounding text. The problem is, that your regex matches *too well*. It only matches the first two decimal places. Therefore the match only includes the first two decimal places.

That means that whatever you will replace that with, will only replace `553.17` and nothing more. For finding decimal numbers this is good. For replacing not so much, here you want to find the whole number with *all* decimal places and then replace it.

So a working replace regex would look like this: `(\d+\.\d{1,2})\d*`. First there is only one capture group, as we don't intend to change the order of numbers around. Second, the point is required as we are only interested to replace numbers that actually have decimal places. Same reason we need at least  one, up to two, decimal places. Every decimal place after that is optional, but will be captured greedily to give the whole number to the match so it will be replaced completely.

```
Match 1: 533.17765
    $1 = 533.17
    Replace 533.17765 with 533.17
```

This regex does not handle thousands-separators btw, if that is required.